# SSRS - PLSQL Developer Connection issue

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, plsqldeveloper

I have a connection issue between SSRS (Report builder) and PLSQL Developer, Would you tell me how can I connect between them please? What do I have to choose as type of connection (Oracle, OLE DB, ...)?

Comment: Any solution please ?

Comment: Hello, can somebody help me please ? Thanks in advance